# Field bindings in peewee

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy, peewee

How I can link fields in `peewee` as in `sqlalchemy`:

```
parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("parent.id"))
```

How to convert this code to peewee?

Answer (score 0):

The very first document in the documentation describes creating a foreign key relationship. Instead of taking the time to write your question and post it here, you could have read that doc. I'm linking it here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#model-definition

Example models:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # This model uses the "people.db" database.

class Pet(Model):
    owner = ForeignKeyField(Person, backref='pets')
    name = CharField()
    animal_type = CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # this model uses the "people.db" database
```

For a self-referential foreign key: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#self-referential-foreign-keys

Example:

```
class Category(Model):
    name = CharField()
    parent = ForeignKeyField('self', null=True, backref='children')
```

Comment: It's a little different. I want to link 2 fields and not create a field with a link to another table

Comment: The foreign key by default links to the primary-key of the related table. If you want to explicitly specify a different column then you can pass `field=Table.column`. Docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#ForeignKeyField